What is the legal situation with sharing social media login details?
There is vaguely newsworthy drama in WordPress land, with the relevant point that organisers of community-organized events have been ordered by the WordPress developer/trademark owner share their login credentials for social networks.  From an answer on our sister site which links the facebook terms of service this is breaches these ToS.  This also says it is similarly a breach to solicit a password.

First thing, you should not share your Facebook password with anyone else. It's a violation of Facebook’s Statement of Rights and Responsibilities to share or solicit a Facebook password.

not share your password, give access to your Facebook account to others or transfer your account to anyone else (without our permission).


I suspect that neither of these things are rare, in that most social media contracts, as well as just about any time one provides a password online, there is a clause forbidding sharing ones password.  Also I suspect there are many times where someone in power over another demands their login details.
However this seems legally dangerous.  It seems clear breach of contract by at least the party giving up the credentials and possibly the party making the request, and in the UK it seems the use of the credentials by the requester would constitute unauthorised access to computer material under the Computer Misuse Act 1990 which is a crime.  I would imagine in the US one would consider the CFAA, ECPA and the DMCA on finding crimes.
What would be the legal situation if someone requests/demands the login credentials for an online service such as social media against the TOS, the other party gives the credentials and they are used by the requester in a way that would be legal if done by the legitimate owner of the account?  Any jurisdiction would be interesting.

Breach of contract
As you note, it is clear breach of contract to share or solicit a Facebook password, and most other subscription type services have similar terms, so, we can probably say this is ubiquitous.
Breaching a contract is something you are entitled to do; that is, it is not criminal or in any way an offence. However, it does expose you to legal consequences in that the other party to the contract can seek redress for the breach. If they have suffered damage from your breach, they can sue for those damages. Depending on the terms of the contract, this breach may also entitle them to terminate the contract without consequences for themselves. Facebook and similar services almost universally give themselves the right to terminate for any user breach.
Tortious interference with contractual relations
A person who has not entered a contract with Facebook is, of course, under no obligations to follow their terms.
However, in common law jurisdictions, if a third-party interferes in a contract by inducing one party to breach the contract and the other party suffers damage, then that third-party opens themselves up to a damages claim.
So, if I solicit your password and Facebook finds out and cancels your account, they can sue me for the loss of  income that arises by you not being a member. Of course, Facebook is free (remember, boys and girls, if you aren't the customer, you're the product), so their direct damages are a bit tenuous. Even for a service like, say, Netflix, where they can point to a genuine loss of revenue, the amount concerned is so low that it's not worth pursuing.
This cause of action is more likely if, say, you are a marquee football player under contract with Chelsea, and Manchester City approaches you with an inducement to break your contract. Expect to see more of these since the EU court has just ruled that FIFA's anti-poaching rules are illegal.
Unauthorised access
Yes, the access is unauthorised, and, where that's a crime, this is a crime.
Sack the developer
They're clearly not very good because there are legitimate ways of accessing Facebook account data that don't require the disclosure of passwords. The fact they don't know how to do this shows they are a shit developer.

This is generally a good answer, thank you.  I feel the "Sack the developer" section may be misinformed, as the "developer" in this case is the owner of the copyright and trademark.  He developed WordPress, one of the most widely used website frameworks.  While I think he is a good developer, he is clearly terrible at the business/politics of open source.
